# Calculator is not taking the Average

Tags: swift, macos, terminal

I was coding a calculator app on swift, and I am very new to swift. So I am lost with the syntax and everything. When I debug my code I get and error of on the code sayign division by 0. I have debugged and everything but I have no idea how to solve it any help would be greatly appreciated, I am just starting out swift and iOS. The application I am making right is for the mac terminal so my program takes the the users input from string and then converts it to an int.

This is the code I am working with

```
    var average = 0;
    let count = nums.count - 1

    for index in 0...nums.count - 2 {
        let nextNum = Int(nums[index])
        average += nextNum!
    }

    return average / count
}
```

Comment: If `nums` has one element then `count = nums.count - 1` is zero (and `average / count` )... why do you subtract one?

Comment: nums.count is an array so for my tests i have , it stores all the values that i would be averaging

Comment: Again: **Why** do you subtract one in `count = nums.count - 1`  (and why does the index only run up to `nums.count - 2)?

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting one from the array elements count, I assume due to the idea that zero based numbering affects it, but there is no need in this case.

You should check for an empty array since this will cause a division by zero. Also you can use `reduce` to simply sum up an array of numbers then divide by the count.

```
func average(of nums: [Float]) -> Float? {
    let count = nums.count
    if (count == 0) { return nil }
    return nums.reduce(0, +) / Float(count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some reason for divisor be 0. As @MartinR said if there is only 1 object in `nums` then `count = nums.count -1` would be zero and `1 / 0` is an undefined state.

One more issue I found that you are looping as `0...nums.count - 2` but it should be `0...nums.count - 1`. You can also write it with less than condition as

`0..<nums.count` or `0..<count`
Use,

```
var average = 0;
let count = nums.count

for index in 0..<count {
    let nextNum = Int(nums[index])
    average += nextNum!
}

return average / count
```

You can use the swift high-order functions for the optimised solution which will return 0 as average even if you do not have any number in your `nums` array. As:

```
let count = nums.count
let avg = nums.reduce(0, +) / count
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try this:

```
var sum = 0;
let count = nums.count

for index in 0...nums.count - 1 {
    let nextNum = Int(nums[index])
    sum += nextNum!
}

return count != 0 ? sum/count : 0
```